# Intermittent ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound during Ruby on Rails Integration Tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, integration-testing

I have integration tests that are intermittently failing, and always with `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` errors. The error takes place inside the controller where a `find` call takes place given an ID from a fixture. It takes place in multiple controllers, though. I never see this behaviour while navigating the site, but I'd say the tests fail about 30-50% of the time. Running the test again after a failure seems to fix the problem.

If I load the fixtures manually into the development database, the ID that doesn't seem to be found is indeed present inside the tables.

I haven't been able to find much info on people having the same problem... any ideas?

**UPDATE**: Here are the contents of test_helper.rb

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
require 'capybara/rails'
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.(yml|csv) for all tests in alphabetical order.
  #
  # Note: You'll currently still have to declare fixtures explicitly in integration tests
  # -- they do not yet inherit this setting
  fixtures :all
  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end
# Transactional fixtures do not work with Selenium tests, because Capybara
# uses a separate server thread, which the transactions would be hidden
# from. We hence use DatabaseCleaner to truncate our test database.
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  # Make the Capybara DSL available in all integration tests
  include Capybara::DSL
  # Make the Capybara Email DSL available in all integration tests
  include Capybara::Email::DSL
  # Stop ActiveRecord from wrapping tests in transactions
  self.use_transactional_fixtures = false
  # Switch to selenium as the default driver for JS support
  Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
  # Only click on visible links!
  Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = true
  teardown do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean       # Truncate the database
    Capybara.reset_sessions!    # Forget the (simulated) browser state
    Capybara.use_default_driver # Revert Capybara.current_driver to Capybara.default_driver
  end
end
```

**UPDATE** Here are the results of running the same test 5 times in a row. I ran the tests, waited until they finished, and then immediately ran them again with the command `rails test:integration`. NOTE: The E and F that are consistent throughout the tests are actually test errors -- I'm working on fixing those. For example, the second test run-through was "correct", but the first showed the spurious error.

```
..E......E..........F.
.........E..........F.
..E......E..........F.
..E......E..........F.
..E....E.E..........F.
```

The errors do occur across two separate tables -- they're not trying to find the same record. But it does appear to be only a subset of the tests that have this issue...

**UPDATE** Here's what the actual error looks like in the test results:

```
  1) Error:
test_browsing_user_snops(BrowseStoriesTest):
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with id=980190962
    /home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:341:in `find_one'
    /home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:312:in `find_with_ids'
    /home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:107:in `find'
    /home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/querying.rb:5:in `find'
    /home/myuser/Projects/myproject/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:18:in `show'
    ...
```

Notice that the error appears when the controller tries to find a record. The relevant line is actually `@user = User.find(params[:id])`. It occurs with other models also, not just the users controller and not just the User model.

Comment: Do you re-establish your entire integration test environment for each test, or just once at the start, or per spec? (When you say integration test are you talking about the typical Rails full stack "unit" test - which, yes, are not unit tests at all by normal standards - or have you gone through the trouble to isolate everything and have true unit test and integration test environments?

Comment: I have never seen this, and a quick google suggests others haven't either.  When you say "intermittent" does this mean "always fails but in different places", or "sometimes works, sometimes fails" and if the latter, "always on the same tests" or "seemingly randomly"?  If the failure is seemingly random, this suggests some timing issue, for example data is saved to the database, but maybe not committed by the time the next test command is issued.  That seems unlikely.  What database?  Any other patterns?

Comment: @cfeduke Hmm... I don't explicitly re-establish any testing environment. I'm just calling `rake test:integration` over and over, and sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. I suppose this means that my unit test and integration test are using the same environments -- the `test` environment (as opposed to development/production).

Comment: @tharrison Intermittent in this case means that sometimes a given integration test in the list will pass, and sometimes it will fail. The error is always a RecordNotFound error. Sometimes only one will fail with RecordNotFound, sometimes a bunch of them. The database in test environment is SQLite. I'm using Capybara for integration testing, so maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: Do you do anything special in any setup or teardown blocks? (rake test:integration is actually new to me, so just now reading the docs)

Comment: @cfeduke I'll add the contents of my test_helper.rb to the question. I'm only using the integration tests built-in to Rails because I assumed it was the 'right' way to do things... I'm a bit new to it!

Comment: Geez -- it's possible that SQLLite (which is a file-based database) has some sort of concurrency issue for certain filesystems (e.g. buffers not flushed or or something), but that just doesn't make sense to me.  There has to be some sort of pattern.

Comment: @tharrison Let me run it 5 times in a row and see what results I get. I'll add another update.

Comment: @aardvarkk its okay, there are numerous ways to do things in Rails all with accompanying out of date blog posts, don't get caught up doing any one thing until you're on your fifth or sixth project and have appropriately cut your teeth (i.e. on your NEXT project try FactoryGirl instead of fixtures)

Comment: based on your test_helper.rb I am assuming you are piecemeal loading the necessary fixtures on a per-integration-test basis, going to look into Capybara and SQLite - as a quick check, how hard would it be to use PostgreSQL or ::shudder:: MySQL to execute tests against just to rule out SQLite?

Comment: @cfeduke I *have* heard about FactoryGirl. I'll try that next time around. I think the fixtures are all available in every text due to calling `fixtures :all`, but I could be mistaken. I just access them inside the integration test by doing something like `amodel(:one)`, with `amodel` having an accompanying `amodel.yml` file in the fixtures folder. I could theoretically switch to MySQL or PostgreSQL. It's all just development right now. Any particular reason PostgreSQL is superior to MySQL? The stuff I read when getting into Rails recommended MySQL as a default.

Comment: @aardvarkk worry about PostgreSQL vs. MySQL later when everything is working fine :) (setup time for MySQL is pretty fast and its a good choice for most projects; PostgreSQL is a more capable RDBMS and if you want to deploy to Heroku you'll need to work locally with PostgreSQL so plusses/minuses to both)

Comment: @aardvarkk keep in mind this comment in your test_helper: `# Note: ... have to declare fixtures explicitly in integration tests -- they do not yet inherit this setting`

Comment: @cfeduke Hmm... not sure this would explain intermittent behaviour? The fixtures do seem to be loading. Ugh... I get really irritated with Rails and all of its crazy behaviours. The "magic" can be more than irritating when it's not working!

Comment: @aardvarkk this is normal in Rails, its a pain at first

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm concerned that there may be a delay during the truncation of data and the speed in which Capybara is driving the web browser which sometimes may result in identity column values starting at an unexpected value (i.e., 7 for record #1 - when you expect 1, because that identity generator has not yet been reset). I have no evidence that this is the case but its my best guess.

Take at [look at item #3 at this URL](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2011/12/three-tips-to-improve-the-performance-of-your-test-suite/). This is a pretty straight-forward hack, set `use_transactional_fixtures` to true and monkeypatch ActiveRecord by pasting that code into your `test_helper.rb`. This could help in eliminating any intermittent disk IO problems that could be a potential problem.

Another thing you can try is restricting your SQLite test database by setting the filename for that database to `:memory:` in your `database.yml` file. This should accomplish the same thing as above - eliminate spurious disk IO that may be causing these intermittent issues.

Comment: I think you're on to something here. So far I've run the whole test suite twice with use_transactional_features set to true and I've gotten the same (very different -- more failures!) results twice in a row. So at least it's repeatable! Stuff that was passing is now failing, but it seems the failures are always the same. I'm gonna run it a few more times to make sure, then the answer is all yours :)

Comment: Not that I *understand* why this setting is a problem, but whatever!

Comment: Yeah -- a bunch of new stuff is failing now (...?!), but at least the results are repeatable. At least that's a start. Not sure if I should report this somewhere as a bug? I have no idea what's even happening...

Comment: Thanks so much for all of your hard work and attention! I really appreciate it.

Comment: I will cut to the chase and save you a lot of time: http://pryrepl.org/ - install it, set your `rails c` to use it, and then in your tests you can `binding.pry` and it will break into a pry session that you can `ls` and `cd some_variable` to examine values; you can even run ActiveRecord queries (`User.find_by_email(...)`) to see just what the database *actually* has at that moment